# How to call Content Assistant Popup of StructuredTextViewer?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, viewer, content-assist

We are developing Eclipse plugin project.
When you select an object in the Editor Area
the properties display in the viewpart below the editor.
The Viewpart contains a viewer with XML content.
I'm using StructuredTextViewer from WPT for this purpose. The syntax highlighting work properly, but the content assistant doesn't.

```
    public class AxelotXmlViewer extends StructuredTextViewer
    {

      public AxelotXmlViewer(Composite parent, IVerticalRuler verticalRuler, IOverviewRuler overviewRuler, boolean showAnnotationsOverview, int styles)
      {
        super(parent, verticalRuler, overviewRuler, showAnnotationsOverview, styles);
        appendVerifyKeyListener(new VerifyKeyListener()
          {

            @Override
            public void verifyKey(VerifyEvent event)
            {   

              // Check for Ctrl+Spacebar call Content Assistant
              if (event.stateMask == SWT.CTRL && event.character == ' ') 
              {
                if (AxelotXmlViewer.this.canDoOperation(StructuredTextViewer.CONTENTASSIST_PROPOSALS))
                  AxelotXmlViewer.this.doOperation(StructuredTextViewer.CONTENTASSIST_PROPOSALS);           
                // Veto this key press to avoid further processing
                event.doit = false;
              }                           
            }
          });

      }

      @Override
      public void setDocument(IDocument document)
        {

          if (document instanceof IStructuredDocument)
          {
            super.setDocument(document);

          }
          else if (document != null)
          {
...    
          }
          else
          {
            super.setDocument(null);
          }
        }

    }
```

Comment: doOperation is called but nothing happens

Comment: I`ve conected source code WTP for debaging. The problem is that StructuredModelManager.getModelManager().getModelForRead doesn`t return a properly model. It must returm DOMModelImpl instance, but realy it gives null.

Comment: <!-- language: lang-java -->

public void inputDocumentChanged(IDocument oldInput, IDocument newInput) {
   if(fContentTypeID == null) {
    if(newInput instanceof IStructuredDocument) {
     IStructuredModel model = null;
     try {
      model = StructuredModelManager.getModelManager().getModelForRead((IStructuredDocument)newInput);
      if(model != null) {
       
     } finally {
      if(model != null) {
       model.releaseFromRead();
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }

Comment: How to higlight syntax in comment anyboy know?